# :: Operator Without Preceding Class or Namespace

Tags: c++, winapi

I am getting started coding a win32 windows application and ran across a c++ syntax that I haven't seen before in some [example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the MSDN.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DemoApp::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    /* Code omitted for clarity */

    ::SetWindowLongPtrW(
    hwnd,
    GWLP_USERDATA,
    PtrToUlong(pDemoApp)
    );

    /* Code omitted for clarity */

}
```

I am used to seeing a class / namespace preceding the :: operator.  What does this mean when there is no preceding identifier.  Also, is there a name for this construct so I can efficiently Google more information?

Thanks!

Comment: check this one ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b451xz31.aspx

Comment: The global namespace has no name.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks for the link, answers my question perfectly.